# 'Access Denied' when attempting DirSync with S.DS

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to set up a [DirSync control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Previously I have [successfully] used the methods found in the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, but I found that the results it returned were only partial objects - I wasn't able to have it return the homeDrive attribute from a user even if I defined it in the SearchRequest's Attributes property.

Thus, I'm attempting to set up DirSync following [some of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180835%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization%28v=vs.90%29) using System.DirectoryServices instead. I was successful in connecting to my test server (only accessible by IP), and I was successful in targeting just one OU and searching for a user, as such:

```
byte[] cookie = null;
root = new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://[MyIPHere]/OU=test ou,DC=company,DC=com", "username", "password");

//Section A - Use this section for a regular search
DirectorySearcher src = new DirectorySearcher(root);
src.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
src.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=myuserhere)";

//Section B - Use this section for a DirSync
//src.DirectorySynchronization = new DirectorySynchronization(
    DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues, cookie);
//src.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";

//Execute the code whichever section is used
SearchResultCollection result = src.FindAll();

int count = result.Count;
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());

foreach (SearchResult res in result)
{
    //do things
}
```

However, when I try to use section B instead of section A, I get an error on the line where I'm setting the int *count*. (I have tried passing no parameters to the constructor of src.DirectorySynchronization as in the example, same result):

> COMException was unhandled
>
> Access is denied.

I only get the error when I try to access the properties of the result object, or try to iterate. If I set a breakpoint on the *int count* line and look at the result object, I see the following in the value column of the result's Count:

> 'result.Count' threw an exception of type
>
> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

I have ensured that my account has the [Replicating Directory Changes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/isrpfeplat/archive/2010/09/20/using-the-dirsync-control.aspx) security access both for the specified OU and the test domain at large (and all other security access possible). I have also tried using a separate domain admin account.

I have the same issue if I try running this on our production domain, passing no credentials when constructing the `DirectoryEntry` object.

Considering that I can successfully retrieve other search results, what is it about this DirectorySynchronization that is causing the access issues, and why isn't it happening when I call `src.FindAll()`?

(I'm open to other options, but I'd like to avoid the USNChanged tracking method for now due to it returning the full objects back, and requiring additional coding on my end.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of a DirSync search must be the root of a directory partition, i.e "DC=company,DC=com" in your case.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677626(v=vs.85).aspx
"Base of the search" in the table.

Some more good C# example for DirSync:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188700.aspx#S1
See section "Finding Your Way with DirectorySearcher".

If you want to track changes only on a OU/container, yes, you will have to use USNChange.